# Streaming multiple users in Twitter API v2

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, twitter-api-v2, twarc2

I am migrating from Twitter APIv1.1 to v2, and trying to stream tweets of users filtered by their ids. I use `twarc.client2.Twarc2` in python and build a list of rules in this form:

```
{'value': 'from:user1 or from:user2 or ...'}
```

I have more than thousand users and since each rule is restricted with 512 characters according to twitter API (because of my account), I splitted user ids to different rules. And while streaming I change rules in time interval of 37 seconds, since API restricts to add only 25 rules in 15 minutes. What I have tried so far is rougly like this:

```
def manage_streaming():
    event = threading.Event()
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=streaming, args=(event,))
    thread1.start()
    index = 0
    while True:
        sleep(37)
        update_rule(index)
        index = 0 if index == max_index else index+1
        if event.is_set():
            break
```

where streaming function is like:

```
def streaming(event):
    results = client.stream(event=event)
    for result in results:
        process_tweet(result)
```

and update_rule function is like:

```
def update_rule(i):
    clear_rules()
    add_rule(rules_2_add[i])
```

It is working correctly, but it takes about 43 minutes for all users to finish streaming and start again.
So my question:

**Is there a better way to stream multiple users in API v2? Or is it possible to open multiple streaming ports with different rules in each of them?**

Thank you in advance. All suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT!!**

I mixed API restrictions, my account is essential so I am allowed to add only 5 rules; I can add 5 rules concurrently or asynchronously after that If I wanna add more rules I need to delete the old ones and wait for 15 mins, there is no way to add more than 5 rules. Still this is not efficient with more users.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for methods and ways I saw that there are two possible ways (not programmatically) to overcome this problem:

1. Upgrade your essential access level account to elevated access level. You can retrieve up to 2 million tweets per month for free and create up to 3 apps in the same project. Moreover, each of these apps accepts up to 25 rules, enabling you to add 12800 character long rules in total. I created nearly 60 rules and added each app at most 25 rule, by this I was able to solve the problem. Also, while creating rules, I compared length of twitter user name and id, then I used smaller one. This is a valid rule:

```
   {'value': 'from:user_1_name or from:user_2_id or ...'}
```

2. If your account is not eligible for elevated access, try to create multiple essential accounts and use all of them to stream.

For more about account levels: [Official Page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, for more details you can visit the following URLs

```py
class TweetListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):

    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet.text)


stream = TweetListener(bearer_token=tw.bearer_token)

stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("from:username01 OR from:username02"))
stream.filter()
```

https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500

[example api v1 and v2 in tweepy](https://gist.github.com/sparack/e8021298115f4a1289a637e25f284daf#streaming-tweets-in-real-time-using-the-1-sampled-stream)

[more stream ruls docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule#type)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for pointing out the announcement. However, it does not answer my question on how to stream more users with limited access level account or add more rules.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32568443)